# Jenkins slave setup fails with private key authentication

Tags: jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration

i am encountering a weird issue when adding a new jenkins slave node.
the steps that i have done are as followed:

1. copied the public key from the master to the slave authorized_keys
2. checked that i can connect from the master to the slave to make sure it works
3. created keys on the slave and copied them to the new credentials.

getting the following error

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUXrk.png)

further more, when i use the private key from the server to connect to it

`ssh -i <path to private key> user@ip`
gives me the same error

`Permission denied (publickey).`

but when i connect without the argument (with my public key) then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding your step 3 - are you saying that you are saving the `slave` private key in jenkins credentials? It should be the master private key you should have in your jenkins credentials and use that to connect to your slave.

Comment: i am getting this error

`SSH Connection failed with IOException: "Connection refused (Connection refused)", retrying in 15 seconds.  There are 9 more retries left.
`

Comment: Looks like that could be many things. You did not answer my question so not sure if your keys are alright. You can also check if the `ssh` service is running: `service ssh status`, you can also try to telnet from master to the slave to see if it can connect: `telnet <slave_ip> 22`. I would start with reviewing the keys, if you put the correct ones and then continue with possible networking issues.

Comment: i did what you told me to.
took the private key from master and put it in the credentials in jenkins.
afterwards i took the public key and put it on the slave
and then i got that error

Comment: @PetrHecko I also came across same issue. Actually I have windows server both master and slave and trying to connect agent with master via ssh. For this purpose ic read ssh private and public key on master node and set private key as credentials on master Jenkins . For slave I created C:\jenkins\.ssh and then authorized_keys file inside it and pasted master ssh public key in it, but I’m still getting the issue authentication failed as posted in the question.can you guide me how I can resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to trust the key, in jenkins you have to select manually trusted key while adding the private key, then below that you have to check the check box for trusting the key, after saving that you'll get on the option to trust the host's key in nodes dash board.